# jQuery mouse hover intent use

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am newbie to `jQuery`. I have this piece of code.Here is the link for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/Rqq6c/). Here you can see when you will make hover on `#flip` it will slide down and when you will make your mouse out it will slide down. Now from this point its working fine. But I want that there will be `hoverIntent` so that if someone will play hover and out with it then it will not affect the slide to run automatic.
My jQuery code looks like this

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `stop` to stop the currently-running animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").hover(function(){
    $("#panel").stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

The first parameter is used to remove queued animation, the second is used for complete the current animation immediately.

Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqq6c/1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content in a container element and attach the hover event to that instead. That way you haven't really stopped hovering over either of the elements.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="flip">Hover on panel to slide the panel down or up</div>
  <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").hover(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

View updated [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vrtPz/)

Answer (score 0):

If the user will just travel with his mouse over the element the slide will not trigger,
 preventing frustrations :) 
will wait for 300ms before showing the `#panel` if the mouse is still over the `#flip`!

**Hover Intent** using Data attribute

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqq6c/2/)**</kbd>

```
var $panel = $('#panel');

$("#flip").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ) {
    return e.type=="mouseenter" ? panelOn() : panelOff() ;
});

function panelOn() {    
   $panel.data('wait', setTimeout(function(){
       $panel.stop().slideDown(600);
   },300) );
}

function panelOff() {
    clearTimeout( $panel.data('wait') );
    $panel.stop().slideUp(600); 
}
```

Additionally, if you want to keep the `#panel` opened once we hover it,
 add to both your elements a parent element, and change the triggering element selector to it's ID